# bulidng containers from compose file fails in portainer

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, portainer

i'm trying to run a stack in portainer from a local git server that should build a couple of containers from the same git server, but it fails when i try to deploy it in portainer.

i stared by making a git repository where i included the projects for the contianers i want to build as sub modules.

i had no problem cloning this repository and building using docker-compose from the command line but when i did the same from portainer i got a "can't locate Dockerfile"

i then changed the docker-compose file to include the git repository at the build line like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  frontend:
    build: http://someaddres/CatalogFrontEnd.git
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    volumes:
      - /opt/mds:/app/mds
    environment:
      - DB_IP=192.168.2.181
      - DB_NAME=Catalog
      - AUTH=ldap
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - /opt/db:/var/opt/mssql/data
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=somthing
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
```

and again it works great from the command line using docker-compose but portainer gives the same "can't locate Dockerfile"

the database starts up just fine but it doesn't build the frontend.